# How do I convert python crypt object to csv so I can call csv methods on the contents

Tags: python, oracle, csv, encryption

My sample code is below: My question is after the code

```
[root@localhost .gnupg]# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import csv

    >>> import gnupg

    >>> import os

    >>> gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome="/home/chefgit/Desktop/.gnupg")

    >>> file = open("/home/chefgit/Desktop/csv/dest/file_100.gpg")

    >>> decrypt = gpg.decrypt_file(file)
```

Ok so here is what I'm trying to do. I got this new job and they give me this first project to work on. Write a script that uses python GNU PG to encrypt and decrypt data. Ok that's the easy part. Then my boss came in and said I must decrypt the data and load it into the database on the fly. We are dealing with Protected Health Information (PHI), so he doesn't want the files lying unencrypted even for one nano second on the disk. I'm supposed to decrypt the files and load them into the database on the fly. From there the data will go into a data lake and then into ODI (Oracle Data Integrator) and through ETL into the Oracle Data Warehouse we are building. But as you can see from the code I've got a problem. I need some way to read the data line by line. But the variable "decrypted" (in my code) is a crypt object. It doesn't let me apply normal readlines method. Ideally I want a way to read the data in using csv.readlines() method so that I can write that into a table in the oracle database. I've tried everything I could but can't figure out what to do. I'm new to python. this is my first python project. Please help me. I need to pull this off to keep this job. I'm on my 6 month probation. After six months they will decide whether to keep me on board or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html?highlight=cstringio#module-StringIO) (or [`cStringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html?highlight=cstringio#module-cStringIO) if available) to convert data into a file like object. This can then be fed to your CSV reader to be processed line by line. The following script gives you an idea how this can be done:

```
import csv
import gnupg
import os
import StringIO

gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome="/home/chefgit/Desktop/.gnupg")
file = open("/home/chefgit/Desktop/csv/dest/file_100.gpg")
decrypt = gpg.decrypt_file(file)
csv_input = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(decrypt))

for row in csv_input:
    print row
```

Comment: Thanks man. I was in a meeting. I will try this and get back here with the results. Once again thank you. I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Thank you so very much sir. you just made my day.

Answer (score 1):

I could depend on whether you are using Python2 or Python3 because `str` in a bytes string in Python2 and a unicode one in Python3. But anyway, the `io` module could help you.

Python2

```
>>> import io
...
>>> decrypt = gpg.decrypt_file(file)
>>> fd = io.BytesIO(str(decrypt))
>>> for line in fd:
        # process line by line here
```

Python3

```
>>> import io
...
>>> decrypt = gpg.decrypt_file(file)
>>> fd = io.StringIO(str(decrypt))
>>> for line in fd:
        # process line by line here
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I was in a meeting. I just got back now. I will apply this and get back here with the results. Thank you so much for taking the time to respond.

Comment: hahaha!!  You two guys just saved my life! well that is just to say I'm super grateful. Both your answers worked. I am using python 2.6 in an oracle Linux 6 environment. Thank you sirs. And please don't ever stop helping. YOU JUST SAVED MY LIFE AT OUR NEXT PROJECT MEETING!  I'm going to mark the first answer as the best one, but really for my purpose, both responses produced results I can use to load this data directly into the database. Once Again thank you Gentlemen.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but just in case data is 'tab' delimited:

```
import io
import csv
data = gpg.decrypt_file(file)
result = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(str(data)), delimiter='\t')
for rec in result:
    # process line by line.
    print(rec['col_header1'], rec['col_header2'], ...)
```